# coffee flights in a six-seat bar

Tags: meaning, phrase-requests

What do *coffee flights* and *six-seat bar* mean in the following post?

> The Orange County Register is now reporting that 39-year-old Duggan plans to open a slow bar adjacent to Portola, offering **coffee flights** and food pairings. “There are three other concepts like this that I know of in the country,” Duggan told the paper.
>
> Here’s a description from Register reporter Nancy Luna:
>
> > *Taking the craft coffee craze up a notch, Duggan plans to launch a “slow bar” called Theorem later this month. The **six-seat slow service coffee bar**, adjacent to Portola, will sell creative cocktails where coffee is the main component.*
>
> [**emphasis added**]

http://dailycoffeenews.com/2012/08/13/oc-coffee-company-portola-to-open-six-seat-slow-bar/

Answer (score 4):

A "six seat bar" is exactly what it sounds like: a bar (i.e. where the bartender is) with six seats (barstools) at it. A "flight of coffees" is a sampling of several different coffees (in separate cups). Cf "flight of beers."